# Displaying correctly legends in barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to display the legend under the y axis, and not as a vertical list but as a horizontal one. If it is not possible, do you have any solution to propose in order to don't have the legend overlapping the graph ?
I found answers to this kind of problem, but I don't understand them.

```
meute1 = c(78.6,9.7,0.6,11.1)
meute2 = c(60.8,35.7,0.2,3.3) 
meute3 = c(61.2,16.5,2.3,20.0) 
meute4 = c(54.6,10.7,9.8,24.9)
meutes=cbind(meute1,meute2,meute3,meute4)
coul= brewer.pal(n = length(meute1), name = 'Set3')

barplot(height = meutes, col=coul, horiz=T,
        names.arg = c("Meute 1","Meute 2","Meute 3", "Meute 4"),
        legend.text = c("Ongulés sauvage", "Petits et moyens mammifères", "Micro-mammifères", "Appâts"), 
        args.legend = list(x = "topright"),las=1)
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the following. You just need to add some arguments to `args.legend`, i.e. `horiz = T` to make it horizontal, `x` to move the legend to the bottom of the plot, `inset` to move the legend down, and `cex` to change the font size. I couldn't get the colors to work but you get the idea:

```r
barplot(height = meutes, horiz=T,
        names.arg = c("Meute 1","Meute 2","Meute 3", "Meute 4"),
        legend.text = c("Ongulés sauvage",
                        "Petits et moyens mammifères",
                        "Micro-mammifères", "Appâts"
                        ), 
        args.legend = list(x = "bottom",       # <- move legend to bottom
                           inset = c(0, -.25), # <- move legend outside plot
                           horiz = T,          # <- make legend horizontal
                           cex = .8),          # <- change legend font size
        las=1
        )
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I was thinking indeed ! Do you know by any chance how do I space equally the labels within the legend box ? I tried 'text.width, but it is very long to find the correct spacing, and it is not very accurate.

Comment: @HannahTamia I don't think there is an easy answer to that question. I've managed to get some control using `text.width = c(20, 25, 0, 17)`, adjusting `cex`, and setting `bty = "n"` to turn off the box (the box looks weird when you start moving the text around). You just have to fiddle around with the paramters.

Comment: @HannahTamia if my answer solves your question could you maybe upvote and click the √ to accept it? That way I get some rep, and other people with the same question know what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpd=TRUE` to allow positioning of the legend outside of the plot like

```
# Add extra space at the bottom of plot area; change clipping to figure
par(mar=c(8.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1), xpd=TRUE)
library(RColorBrewer)

barplot(height = meutes, col=coul, horiz=T,
        names.arg = c("Meute 1","Meute 2","Meute 3", "Meute 4"),
        legend.text = c("Ongulés sauvage", "Petits et moyens mammifères", "Micro-mammifères", "Appâts"), 
        args.legend = list(x = "bottom", text.width = c(25, 30, 0, 17), 
                       bty='n', horiz = T, inset=-0.2, cex = .8), las=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I added 'xpd=TRUE' after 'x="topright",' but nothing happened